# How to mutate user's session in nextauth when you change user data?

Tags: session, next.js, prisma, next-auth

I want to update the user's data but after updating the user's data how to make also the change appear in session?

**[...nextauth].js**

```
    callbacks: {
    jwt: ({ token, user }) => {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
        token.name = user.name;
        token.surname = user.surname;
        token.email = user.email;
        token.role = user.role;
      }
      // Here, check the token validity date
      if (token.tokenExpiration < Date.now()) {
        // Call the endpoint where you handle the token refresh for a user
        const user =  axios.post(
          `${process.env.API_URL}/auth/authentication/refresh`,
          {
            refreshToken: token.refreshToken,
          }
        );
        // Check for the result and update the data accordingly
        return { ...token, ...user };
      }
      return token;
    },
    session: ({ session, token }) => {
      if (token) {
        session.id = token.id;
        session.name = token.name;
        session.surname = token.surname;
        session.email = token.email;
        session.role = token.role;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
  secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
  jwt: {
    secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
    encryption: true,
    maxAge: 5 * 60 * 1000,
  },
```

**api/user/index.js**
Here I update the user content, what should I do to update the session object detail

```
const updateUser = await prisma.user.update({
  where: {
    email: 'test@email.io',
  },
  data: {
    name: 'User',
  },
})
```

**session object**

```
    name  : Company
email : test@email.io
expires : 2022-04-26T18:44:36.424Z
id  : 2
name  : Company
surname : Surname
email : test@email.io
role  : 2
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. What did you do to achieve this? It is driving me crazy

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and have a hacky workaround. In the `session` callback, get the user from the database. This callback is triggered whenever the session is checked ([docs](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#session-callback)), so you can call `getSession()`, `useSession()`, or even `signIn()` somewhere after you update the user.

```js
async function getUserFromDB(accessToken) {
  // I'm not super familiar with prisma but you get the idea
  const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
    // logic to get user
    // maybe it needs your accessToken
  });
  return user;
}
```

```js
// [...nextAuth].js
session: ({ session, token }) => {
  if (token) {
    session = await getUserFromDB(token.accessToken);
  }
  return session;
}
```

Obvious drawback: There is a call to get the user from the database anytime the session is checked.